# Python - Sklearn - ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm encountering problems with import sklearn.

I'have installed the package throught pip but python can't import the library. I'm using python 2.7 on a Windows 10 environment.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classification.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

I have read that someone find solution by installing SciPy (scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz) but when I try to install via pip the prompt return me this message:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\filipp~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-mhb0vd\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\filipp~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-jsdbd3-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\filipp~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mhb0vd\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\filipp~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mhb0vd\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "c:\users\filipp~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mhb0vd\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\filipp~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-mhb0vd\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\filipp~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-jsdbd3-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\filipp~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-mhb0vd\scipy\
```

Thanks for the help,

Filippo.

Answer (score 1):

Download it from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy). Then change the path to the file with cd in cmd. Afterwards do `pip install filename.whl`. Of course use the actual filename.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tryed before with the libraries downloaded from the url you give me but specifying the path in the commanda pip install "C:\........". With the tip about change the path with cd I manage to install scipy but the problem about sklearn remains...

Comment: Have you also restarted the shell?

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal (cmd) and try these before you try to import the sklearn.

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

or

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Also make sure your have numpy and scipy:

```
pip install numpy 
pip install scipy
```

---

**TRY THIS 1:**

Restart the python shell after installing scipy !

---

**TRY THIS 2:**

Install numpy+mkl package from [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn) and after successful installation restart the python.

To install the whl file use: `pip install some-package.whl`

***If nothing works......***

---

**TRY THIS 3:**

Set Up System Path Variable for Python and the PYTHONPATH Environment Variable

System Variables: add C:\Python34 into path

User Variables: add new: (name)PYTHONPATH (value)C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages;

---

**Final thing to try:**

Install anaconda from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

and then run: `conda install scikit-learn`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have installed numpy and scipy. 
'C:\Users\Filippo-Leoncini\Downloads>pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in c:\python27\lib\site-packages'

'C:\Users\Filippo-Leoncini\Downloads>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages'

'C:\Users\Filippo-Leoncini\Downloads>pip install sklearn
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from sklearn)'

Comment: @if you type pip in the cmd, does it recognize the pip command?

Comment: @FilippoLeoncini then can you try to use: pip install -U scikit-learn ? and then try to import a sklearn function?

Comment: yes I have scikit-learn installed but when I try to import sklearn from python it gives me the error message I have written in the post

Comment: @FilippoLeoncini unistall sklearn and reinstall using  pip. also run cmd always as administrator !

Comment: I did that 3 times I think

Comment: yes I'have also tried that but the same error appears: 
  File "classification.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build

Comment: I have followed all your instructions but nothing change. The problem seems to be with __check_build, as said in the response of the prompt:

'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classification.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149015/discussion-between-sera-and-filippo-leoncini).